# Using XStream to deserialize an XML > Object

Tags: java, xml, xstream, xmlconvert

I am creating an application and I want the users to be able to have multiple profiles but how would I save the info of the profile like the Strings and Integers. I could use XStream to create a XML file but I'm unsure how to recreate the profile from the XML file. Here is the profile code I have

```
class Profile {

String name;
int dartsThrown;
int totalScore;
float average;
int num100, num120, num140, num180;

public Profile(){

}

public Profile(String thename){
    name = thename;
}

public void setName(String thename){
    name = thename;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getDartsThrown(){
    return dartsThrown;
}

public int getTotalScore(){
    return totalScore;
}

public float getAverage(){
    return average;
}

public int get100s(){
    return num100;
}

public int get120s(){
    return num120;
}

public int get140s(){
    return num140;
}

public int get180s(){
    return num180;
}

}
```

If I had an XML file which contains this text

```
<Profile>
    <name>Mitch</name>
    <darts-thrown>100</darts-thrown>
    <total-scrore>100</total-scrore>
    <average>100.0</average>
    <100+>100</100+>
    <120+>100</120+>
    <140+>100</140+>
    <180s>100</180s>
</Profile>
```

How would I go about recreating a profile from the XML. I want to display the info about the profile like name, dartsThrown etc. So how could I use XStream to recreate the profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer for your question thought you can work like this. Here problem with your tag `<100+>` in your xml file, but tag name should be character data or markup. So I would suggest while serializing give its name like `s100`,`s120`.... So that it will treat these tag as character data and you will be able to deserialize it using aliasAttribute method. If so then you can do like this:

```
XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
stream.alias("Profile", Profile.class);
stream.aliasAttribute(Profile.class, "dartsThrown", "darts-thrown");
stream.aliasAttribute(Profile.class, "totalScore", "total-scrore");
stream.aliasAttribute(Profile.class, "num100", "s100");
................
.................
..................

To access these value convert it using fromXML method

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("xmlFile.xml");
Profile profile = (Profile)stream.fromXML(fileReader);
System.out.println("Name: "+profile.getName());
..............
..............
```